# query an object from a list using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

how can I query to return just the students from room:102 with age >= 18??
I want to get an output like:

```
    {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 21,
        "books": [
               {
                "title": "algebra",
                "pages": 300,
                "author": "Jkrowling"
               }
           ]
        }
```

And document as below

```
{
"teacher": "teachername",
"room": 102,
"students": [
        {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 21,
        "books": [
               {
                "title": "algebra",
                "pages": 300,
                "author": "Jkrowling"
               }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following aggregation will help

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$students"},
     {"$match":{"room":102,"students.age":{"$gt":18}}}).pretty()
```

Comment: any non-aggregate way to do this?

Comment: If students array having only single value then it possible using following query `db.collectionName.find({"room":102,"students.age":{"$gt":18}}).pretty()` or if stiudents contains more value then used aggregation